# `<=': comparison of String with nil failed (ArgumentError)

Tags: ruby, iterator, comparison, each, null

I am testing whether array elements are greater than or equal to elements of smaller indices.

I get the error message from the subject line if I use the following loop

```
return true if order.each_index {|i| order[i ] <= order[i+1]}
```

I understand the last element of my array(order) can't be compared to a non-existant element.

Comparing a value to nil is impossible.

I don't, however understand why the following loop doesn't return the same error

```
(0...(order.length - 1)).all? do |i|
  order[i] <= order[i + 1]
end
```

It seems that at some point, `i = order.length-1`
This means `order[i+1]` is a `nil` value (`order.length`)

Apparently not?

Comment: `order.each_cons(2).all?{|e1, e2| e1 <= e2}`, avoiding these index problems.

Answer (score 2):

No, because three dots `...` here `(0...(order.length - 1))` mean 'without last element', so last value would be `order.length - 2`.

You'll encounter the same error if you try `(0..(order.length - 1))`.

Check [Range documentation](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Range.html):

> Ranges may be constructed using the s..e and s...e literals
>
> Those created using ... exclude the end value

Comment: Thanks for the help.  I know this is years later, but I'm happy to finally have an answer ; P